# Using a VPS with 64MB Ram to run a process that takes maximum 600+ MB of Ram

Tags: virtual-machine, vps, cloud-hosting

I'm new to all the Cloud computing and VM thing. I have a VPS with 768MB ram (1GB burstable), when I check my dashboard for the processing, I see that the average usage is 178MB and the Maximum is 618MB.

What will happen if I run the same script on another VPS, but this VPS has 64MB. would it kill the process? or would it use something like virtual memory from the disk space?

The script in PHP, and its crawling web pages and saves some text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may kill the process and set off alarms, or go into swap (which will slow the entire system down and be VERY noticeable anyways); it's hard to say, it depends mostly on the host's configuration.

If I were the host though, and you ended up using that much RAM on a VPS that's supposed to have *just* 64MB, you'd likely have your account terminated entirely.

Comment: dont these systems have Virtual Memory thing where it uses the hard disk for memory, like the normal Desktop OS?

Comment: @user836252 Like I said, it depends mostly on the host itself.  Some do, some don't.  Some hosts detect if a certain amount of swap is used , some also limit the amount of swap you *can* use.  It varies so much that there is no definite answer available.

Comment: The normal behavior running a program that uses more than available RAM with no SWAP consieration is to being killed.